# Deploy Applications with AppJS?

Tags: node.js, appjs

How to I create a stand alone application with AppJS?  I read the tutorial but I cannot find where it is that you actually convert the source code into an "application" with its own "frame" and what not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the pre-packaged distribution for your architecture: http://appjs.com/#download. Extract the zip and you will get a "hello world" application, click on app.sh or app.exe on windows to run the application.

You can then modify index.html to change the look of the application, it is normal html so you can also include jquery and anything else you want. The app.js javascript is then run inside node so it can use node modules, read the local hard disk and so on.

There is more help available at: https://github.com/appjs/appjs/wiki.